# Is there a stopwatch in Java?

Tags: java, stopwatch, milliseconds

Is there a stopwatch in Java?
On Google I only found code of stopwatches that don't work - they always return 0 milliseconds.

This code I found doesn't work and I don't see why.

```
public class StopWatch {
  
  private long startTime = 0;
  private long stopTime = 0;
  private boolean running = false;
  
  
  public void start() {
    this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.running = true;
  }
  
  
  public void stop() {
    this.stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.running = false;
  }
  
  
  //elaspsed time in milliseconds
  public long getElapsedTime() {
    long elapsed;
    if (running) {
      elapsed = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
    } else {
      elapsed = (stopTime - startTime);
    }
    return elapsed;
  }
  
  
  //elaspsed time in seconds
  public long getElapsedTimeSecs() {
    long elapsed;
    if (running) {
      elapsed = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000);
    } else {
      elapsed = ((stopTime - startTime) / 1000);
    }
    return elapsed;
  }
}
```

Comment: And how do you determin it didn't work ? (perhaps you're measuring something that takes less time to execute than the accuracy of System.currentTimeMillis())

Comment: Please post the code how you are testing this class...

Comment: Just wanted to note that this is one of the textbook questions in "Introduction to Java Programming, Comprehensive Version (9th Edition)".

Comment: Please don't use `currentTimeMillis()` for production, as it's **tied to system date/time and is not guaranteed to be monotonous** (e.g. you can get negative elapsed time). For measuring time use `nanoTime()` – it's guaranteed to be monotonous and intended exactly for measuring purpose. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You'll find one in

http://commons.apache.org/lang/

It's called

```
org.apache.commons.lang.time.StopWatch
```

But it roughly does the same as yours. If you're in for more precision, use

```
System.nanoTime()
```

See also this question here:

[Time measuring overhead in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640409/time-measuring-overhead-in-java)

Answer (score 102):

Use [Guava's `Stopwatch` class](https://guava.dev/releases/24.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html).

> An object that measures elapsed time in nanoseconds. It is useful to measure elapsed time using this class instead of direct calls to `System.nanoTime()` for a few reasons:
>
> - An alternate time source can be substituted, for testing or performance reasons.
> - As documented by `nanoTime`, the value returned has no absolute meaning, and can only be interpreted as relative to another timestamp returned by `nanoTime` at a different time. `Stopwatch` is a more effective abstraction because it exposes only these relative values, not the absolute ones.
>
> Basic usage:
>
> ```java
> Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
> doSomething();
> stopwatch.stop(); // optional
>
> Duration duration = stopwatch.elapsed();
>
> log.info("time: " + stopwatch); // formatted string like "12.3 ms"
> ```

Comment: guavas stopwatch is missing `getStartTime()`, apache is missing `isRunning()` ahhhh

Comment: @ToKra What would you do with the start time anyway? Since it's nano time, you can't use it for anything meaningful anyway, as described in the docs.

Comment: Now you use this to get the milliseconds: long stopWatch = stopWatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

Comment: Which guava version is it? I used 1.8 and it didn't find the Stopwatch class

Answer (score 89):

Now you can try something like:

```
Instant starts = Instant.now();
Thread.sleep(10);
Instant ends = Instant.now();
System.out.println(Duration.between(starts, ends));
```

Output is in ISO 8601.

Comment: Quick and easy, thank you very much!  Helps keep track of task duration from start.

Comment: What if you change the system time during the sleep?

Comment: @Peteter its only an example. If you're on a linux box you must deal with hardware clock and kernel managed clock. If you change hardware clock, none will be affected but in kernel managed clock you will be in trouble: Instant.now() get the system time and will show a wrong time interval.

Comment: I did not even know it worked on Android. Good to know :)

Comment: Not forgetting java.time.Instant is immutable and thread safe :)

Comment: Lack of import statements aside, this throws an InterruptedException.

Comment: With java 8 imports, It’s only a sample, David. Please adapt before going to production.

Answer (score 58):

Spring provides an elegant `org.springframework.util.StopWatch` class ([`spring-core`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#spring-core) module).

```
StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();

stopWatch.start();
// Do something
stopWatch.stop();

System.out.println(stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis());
```

Answer (score 9):

There's no built in Stopwatch utility but as of JSR-310 (Java 8 Time) you can do this simply.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
// Do stuff
long seconds = now.until(ZonedDateTime.now(), ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
```

I haven't benchmarked this properly but I would guess using Guava's Stopwatch is more effective.

Answer (score 8):

The code doesn't work because elapsed variable in `getElapsedTimeSecs()` is not a `float` or `double`.

Answer (score 7):

Use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the start time and the end time and calculate the difference.

```
class TimeTest1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
      total += i;
    }

    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    System.out.println(elapsedTime);
  }
}
```

[More info at this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPerformance/article.html)

Comment: As said elsewhere, currentTimeMillis() is tied to system date/time and is not guaranteed to be monotonous (e.g. you can get negative elapsed time).

Comment: Do not use System.currentTimeMillis() to measure elapsed time.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
/*
 * calculates elapsed time in the form hrs:mins:secs
 */
public class StopWatch
{ 
    private Date startTime;

    public void startTiming()
    {
        startTime = new Date();
    }

    public String stopTiming()
    {
        Date stopTime = new Date();
        long timediff = (stopTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime())/1000L;
        return(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(timediff));
    }

}
```

Use:

```
StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
...
sw.startTiming();
...
String interval = sw.stopTiming();
```

Comment: DateUtils is part of Apache Commons, why not just use their StopWatch?

Comment: In most cases you'll use some common library like mentioned in other answers (Apache Commons for instance). You can even take only parts of the library with if you don't need everything.

Answer (score 3):

use : com.google.common.base.Stopwatch, its simple and easy.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
<artifactId>guava</artifactId>
<version>23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

example:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.start();

"Do something"

logger.debug("this task took " + stopwatch.stop().elapsedTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) + " mills");
```

this task took 112 mills

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class millis extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Runnable
    {

     private long startTime;
     private final static java.text.SimpleDateFormat timerFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("mm : ss.SSS");
     private final JButton startStopButton= new JButton("Start/stop");
     private Thread updater;
     private boolean isRunning= false;
     private final Runnable displayUpdater= new Runnable()
         {
         public void run()
             {
             displayElapsedTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - millis.this.startTime);
         }
     };
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
         {
         if(isRunning)
             {
             long elapsed= System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
             isRunning= false;
             try
                 {
                 updater.join();
                 // Wait for updater to finish
             }
             catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
             displayElapsedTime(elapsed);
             // Display the end-result
         }
         else
             {
             startTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
             isRunning= true;
             updater= new Thread(this);
             updater.start();
         }
     }
     private void displayElapsedTime(long elapsedTime)
         {
         startStopButton.setText(timerFormat.format(new java.util.Date(elapsedTime)));
     }
     public void run()
         {
         try
             {
             while(isRunning)
                 {
                 SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(displayUpdater);
                 Thread.sleep(50);
             }
         }
         catch(java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ite)
             {
             ite.printStackTrace(System.err);
             // Should never happen!
         }
         catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
         // Ignore and return!
     }
     public millis()
         {
         startStopButton.addActionListener(this);
         getContentPane().add(startStopButton);
         setSize(100,50);
         setVisible(true);
     }
     public static void main(String[] arg)
         {
         new Stopwatch().addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
             {
             public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                 {
                 System.exit(0);
             }
         });
         millis s=new millis();
         s.run();
     }
}
```

Comment: As said elsewhere, currentTimeMillis() is tied to system date/time and is not guaranteed to be monotonous (e.g. you can get negative elapsed time).

Answer (score 2):

try this http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/Stopwatch.java.html

that's very easy

```
Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
// Do smth. here
double time = st.elapsedTime(); // the result in millis
```

This class is a part of stdlib.jar

Answer (score 2):

Simple out of the box Stopwatch  class:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

public class StopWatch {

    Instant startTime, endTime;
    Duration duration;
    boolean isRunning = false;

    public void start() {
        if (isRunning) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Stopwatch is already running.");
        }
        this.isRunning = true;
        startTime = Instant.now();
    }

    public Duration stop() {
        this.endTime = Instant.now();
        if (!isRunning) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Stopwatch has not been started yet");
        }
        isRunning = false;
        Duration result = Duration.between(startTime, endTime);
        if (this.duration == null) {
            this.duration = result;
        } else {
            this.duration = duration.plus(result);
        }

        return this.getElapsedTime();
    }

    public Duration getElapsedTime() {
        return this.duration;
    }

    public void reset() {
        if (this.isRunning) {
            this.stop();
        }
        this.duration = null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
sw.start();
    // doWork()
sw.stop();
System.out.println( sw.getElapsedTime().toMillis() + "ms");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
public class StopWatch { 

      private long startTime = 0;
      private long stopTime = 0;

      public StopWatch()
      {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      }

      public void start() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      }

      public void stop() {
        stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("StopWatch: " + getElapsedTime() + " milliseconds.");
        System.out.println("StopWatch: " + getElapsedTimeSecs() + " seconds.");
      }

      /**
       * @param process_name
       */
      public void stop(String process_name) {
            stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(process_name + " StopWatch: " + getElapsedTime() + " milliseconds.");
            System.out.println(process_name + " StopWatch: " + getElapsedTimeSecs() + " seconds.");
      }      

      //elaspsed time in milliseconds
      public long getElapsedTime() {
          return stopTime - startTime;
      }

      //elaspsed time in seconds
      public double getElapsedTimeSecs() {
        double elapsed;
          elapsed = ((double)(stopTime - startTime)) / 1000;
        return elapsed;
      }
}
```

Usage:

```
StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
// do something
watch.stop();
```

Console:

```
StopWatch: 143 milliseconds.
StopWatch: 0.143 seconds.
```

Comment: Although this may or may not be what was being asked for in the question, your answer helped me with my problem. Thank you.

Comment: `currentTimeMillis()` is tied to system date/time and is not guaranteed to be monotonous (e.g. you can get negative elapsed time).

Comment: If you decide to build your own, just use `System.nanoTime()` to always get correct results.

Answer (score 2):

**Performetrics** provides a convenient Stopwatch class, just the way you need. It can measure wall-clock time and more: it also measures CPU time (user time and system time) if you need.
It's small, free and you can download from Maven Central.
More information and examples can be found here: https://obvj.net/performetrics

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.start();

// Your code

sw.stop();
sw.printStatistics(System.out);

// Sample output:
// +-----------------+----------------------+--------------+
// | Counter         |         Elapsed time | Time unit    |
// +-----------------+----------------------+--------------+
// | Wall clock time |             85605718 | nanoseconds  |
// | CPU time        |             78000500 | nanoseconds  |
// | User time       |             62400400 | nanoseconds  |
// | System time     |             15600100 | nanoseconds  |
// +-----------------+----------------------+--------------+
```

You can convert the metrics to any time unit (nanoseconds, milliseconds, seconds, etc...)

PS: I am the author of the tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a convenient one here:

https://github.com/varra4u/utils4j/blob/master/src/main/java/com/varra/util/StopWatch.java

Usage:

```
final StopWatch timer = new StopWatch();
System.out.println("Timer: " + timer);
System.out.println("ElapsedTime: " + timer.getElapsedTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

[Java Stopwatch Fully Working Solution](https://coderichjava.blogspot.com/2019/07/java-stopwatch-program.html)

Here you will get a fully working solution.

Just a snippet from the above-linked solution:

You can create a class like below code and use this class' start and stop method before and after the code section, you want to measure the time taken.

```
public class Stopwatch{
  private long startTime;
  private long stopTime;

  /**
   starting the stop watch.
  */
  public void start(){
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
  }

  /**
   stopping the stop watch.
  */
  public void stop()
  {     stopTime = System.nanoTime(); }

  /**
  elapsed time in nanoseconds.
  */
  public long time(){
        return (stopTime - startTime);
  }

  public String toString(){
      return "elapsed time: " + time() + " nanoseconds.";
  }
```

}

Thank you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks @ASMackay for your suggestion. I completely agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import com.google.common.base.Stopwatch;

public class StopwatchTest {
     
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 60);
        stopwatch.stop(); // optional
        long millis = stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println("Time in milliseconds "+millis);
        System.out.println("that took: " + stopwatch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [Stopwatch](https://github.com/JumperBot/Java-SomeUtils/blob/master/src/SomeUtils/Clock/Stopwatch.java) that has everything you might need in it.

I even [documented](https://github.com/JumperBot/Java-SomeUtils/tree/master/src/SomeUtils/Clock#stopwatchjava) it!

And [I also compiled it](https://github.com/JumperBot/Java-SomeUtils/tree/master/build/SomeUtils/Clock) for faster usage.

Here's an example:

```
//...
  //For demo only!
  public static void main(String[]a){
    final Stopwatch stopwatch=new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.start();
    try{
      java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(Exception e){}
    stopwatch.split();
    System.out.println("Time elapsed in nanoseconds: "+stopwatch.getTimeElapsed());
    System.out.println("Time elapsed in milliseconds: "+stopwatch.getTimeElapsed(Stopwatch.millis));
    System.out.println("Time elapsed in seconds: "+stopwatch.getTimeElapsed(Stopwatch.seconds));
    try{
      java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(Exception e){}
    stopwatch.split();
    final long[][] laps=stopwatch.getLaps();
    for(long[] lap:laps){
      System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(lap));
    }
  }
//...
```

This is not for promotion, [made this](https://github.com/JumperBot/Java-SomeUtils/) to help people not waste their time in coding classes themselves!