# Java Basic Timing

Tags: java, timing

Currently my project has no timing and is satisfactory but it would be a lot cleaner if I had timing. I would like to have it so after I declared whatever needs to be I can do something like:

```
if (timer == 2000) {
    System.out.println("2 seconds have passed since "timer" was declared!");
}
```

I haven't seen that much that went over this. Sorry if I'm missing something. I'm just looking for the best way to do this.

**EDIT**
I've been asked for more detail on why I need this so... btw this is for a zombie game

```
while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){
    if (whatever == 2 seconds){    //I obviously know a don't right the word seconds next the number 2
        for(int z = 0; z < 2; z++){
            SpawnaZombieAt(leftcorner,20,speed);
        }
     }
}
```

if I'm not clear enough I am trying to start some sort of timer. then for every 2 seconds or so 2 more zombies will spawn

Comment: Why don't you provide more specifics on what you hope to accomplish by doing something like this? Use **edit** under your question to add more details to it.

Comment: The best way to provide timed events in Java depends on the exact requirements. The core API offers a number of timer classes of varying constraints and accuracy. There are also a number of 3rd party APIs. Be more specific in your requirements.

Comment: Also, the chances of anything timing-related equaling *precisely* 2000 milliseconds are low.

Comment: Are you trying to add measurement/instrumentation to your project (e.g., to measure performance) OR are you trying to schedule activities to occur a specific time?  If the latter, what resolution are you looking for (subsecond? or "run this hourly, give or take?" or something in the middle?)

Comment: This is in a game and it is so every 2 seconds there will be a zombie that spawns.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `System.nanoTime()`? The first is a low precision counter that corresponds to UTC, while the latter is a high precision timer that can be used to determine elapsed time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to launch a specific action after a specific delay, you can use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) - for example:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("2 seconds have passed since this action was scheduled!");
    }
}, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And it will print your sentence after 2 seconds.

If you are after a stopwatch, the answers to [this question propose several alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255738/is-there-a-stopwatch-in-java).

**EDIT**

Following your edit, the `ScheduledExecutorService` has a [`scheduleAtFixedRate` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) that would enable you to run a specific action every 2 seconds for example.

Comment: I'm looking more to make this with the System.currentTimeMillis thing and some variables though