# Does it make sense to use Java Web frameworks in non-web projects?

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a machine learning library and I need a stopwatch to
measure execution time for a method. It turns out Spring has a nice one,
but does it make sense to use Spring for a non-web project? The good
side is of course reusing code, but any downsides?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`Spring` isn't just made for Web application. `Spring MVC` is the request-based framework that you normally used for web application. Now, if you only want the `stopwatch` utilities, nothing prevents you to only include the `spring-core` jar in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Spring is not a web framework. Spring MVC sub-project is. Also Spring support multiple other web frameworks.

That being said you are free to use Spring IoC, AOP, persistence, etc. in desktop, standalone applications. I do it every day.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some Apache projects clone a few methods (or classes) from other Apache projects just to avoid adding a jar dependency when very specific functionality is all that is needed.

An alternative to including spring could be to use a more general purpose library. Two suggestions that are made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255738/is-there-a-stopwatch-in-java) are Google Guava and Apache Commons Lang. I use both and the odds of finding other useful general purpose utilities in those projects is high.