# JavaFX - Using time as a variable for a line chart

Tags: java, timer, javafx

I am essentially trying to create a visual representation of the memory being used in my program. I have created a LineChart and set the Y-axis to be Memory used, and the X-axis to be time. My question is, what is the best way to set up a timer, so that incoming data about memory usage can be paired with the current time.

By this I mean, I want to start a timer when the window displays, and continue to count up (possibly with millisecond precision), and so I can say that after the program has been running for this long, this is the amount of memory used.

What would be the best resources to use for this task?

Answer (score 0):

The best bet would probably just to use System.currentTimeMillis(); and set it to a variable when you start the count, then call it again and compare the saved value with the new timer to get your time.

so..

```
Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
//Do whatever stuff
long timeElapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
```

One thing to keep in mind with this though, is currentTimeMillis() is platform dependent on how granular it is. On unix-based you get 1 ms. of a granularity minimum, I think on windows it's 50. So if you need something more accurate than 50 ms. time steps, you might need a different method.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a StopWatch to measure the time. Please go through the following links

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8255766/1759128

There are many alternatives in different answers of the question. You can use any of them !