# How to calculate the running time of method in java?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, runtime

how I can make my program to calculate the running time of a method once the user click JButton until the result shown in JTextBox? i don't want the whole program running time.thanks
the code is this. and i have another error in the last line (long can't be converted to string). what i can do to set the result in jtextbox?
and it still calculate the whole running time. what i want is to calculate only the encryption time to compare between different keys.

```
     long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     byte[]  plain = plaintext.getText().getBytes();
     byte[] K = key.getText().getBytes();
     byte[] encrypted = encrypt(plain, K);
     String a = bytesToHex(encrypted);
     encryptedtext.setText(a);

    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    time.setText(elapsedTime);
```

Comment: Have you tried just... measuring it? There are a lot of inbuilt methods to get the current time. Just take a stamp before and after and calculate the difference.

Comment: Try `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: @Ben i tried. but it calculate the whole running time. how i can take stamp before and after?

Comment: Guava Stopwatch.

Comment: Take a timestamp before you start your "I want to measure this" part of the code. And after it. I don't really see how you could  think of doing it differently.

Comment: @NewUser i did :( but i need something to make it only calculating that particular method. not the other things in program like when the user type something. you know

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: @ays None of us can see your code. We don't know what you tried or why it didn't work. We can't tell you exactly what lines to add where because we haven't got your code.

Comment: @BenWatson so i make stopwatch as break once the result is out? and i want that time to be shown in another textbox. how i can do that?

Comment: @khelwood sorry I'm out. ;') but I'll add that once i get homo. besides i will try stopwatch as BenWatson says. thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do this by calculating *startTime and endTime*

```
public void someMethod() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Your actual code

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime = endTime - startTime;

    System.out.println("Total Time :: " + totalTime + "ms");
}
```

To convert long to String, please use this function `String.valueOf(long)`

Comment: that how my code look likes. the problem that code will go call method from outside the button. and i noticed it calculate the whole running time

Comment: It will be better if you post some sample code like where is your call method going.

Comment: @ays You want to calculate time only for this method right? `byte[] encrypted = encrypt(plain, K);` Then insert `startTime` code before that line.

Comment: yes exactly. Thank you so much. But another problem is that when i enter same text and same key it doesn’t give exactly the same time :( is there might b wrong with my code or that is fine?

Comment: @ays time may very for every input depends upon the performance (we can say depends upon memory, CPU process like that). So no wrong with your code.

Comment: aha i see thank you. No matter what it will give different results but close because it depends on the CPU?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch().start();

 //your code

  timer.stop();
  System.out.println(timer.getElapsedTime());
```

or

```
  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

//your code

  long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
  System.out.println(elapsedTime);
```

}

Comment: I hope there is no Stopwatch class in java. But its available in [Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255738/is-there-a-stopwatch-in-java)

Comment: Stopwatch is Guava class https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html
but you can do with second method

Comment: Heard downloading libraries from apache is hard to work with. i tried to download one with binaryCodec :(

Comment: @VazgenTorosyan still same result. calculate the whole running time :(

Answer (score 0):

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
callToYourMethod();
long end = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(end - start);
```

Comment: still same result :(