# Performance overhead from System.getCurrentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, performance, optimization

I'm making a sort of probability simulator that will run for either a certain amount of  time, or for a certain amount of repetitions. I'm looking to optimize it, and it's currently multi-threaded with each `ProbabilityWorker` extending `Thread`, and the main program will automatically allocate `n` threads, where `n` is however many threads are available (example: on my Core i3-7100U, this is 4).

I'm analyzing the performance of this, and I'm realizing that the methodology I'm using to get the current time with respect to the end time is causing a lot of overhead.

For the mode where it can "run for a certain amount of time," I was making `new Date` objects as a part of the loop condition, then I changed it to a faster `System.currentTimeMillis()` to try and save time, but I'm noticing even that induces overhead.

My `run` function looks like this:

```
public void run() {
    if (mode) {
        while (completed < repitions) {
            resultSet[randy.nextInt(o)]++;
            completed++;
        }
    } else {
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
            resultSet[randy.nextInt(o)]++;
            completed++;
        }
    }
    done = true;
}
```

Where `mode` is `true` if running for an amount of repetitions, `randy` is a Random, `o` is the amount of possible outcomes, and `endTime` is the end point in milliseconds, system time (which could be modified, program takes in an amount of seconds, and `endTime` is calculated by the current time plus `secondsInput * 1000`).

In addition, on the same Core i3-7100U, these are my performance statistics:

```
DE-WEY-LAPTOP:/mnt/c/Users/danny/Documents/Programming/Data Structures/Probability$ java Main -n 10000000000

Running 10000000000 repitions of the probability simulator with 2 possible outcomes.
4 threads detected on system; doing 2500000000 repitions per thread.
Done. Gathering results from worker threads...
Done. Printing results...
Outcome 1: 4999997330 out of 10000000000 (49.9999733%)
Outcome 2: 5000002670 out of 10000000000 (50.0000267%)
Time taken: 43.443 seconds (2.301866813986143E8 ops/sec)

DE-WEY-LAPTOP:/mnt/c/Users/danny/Documents/Programming/Data Structures/Probability$ java Main -t 44

Running the probability simulator for 44 seconds using 4 threads.
Done. Gathering results from worker threads...
Done. Printing results...
Outcome 1: 141568074 out of 283130850 (50.000935609807264%)
Outcome 2: 141562776 out of 283130850 (49.999064390192736%)
Time taken: 44 seconds (6434792.045454546 ops/sec)
```

My question is, is there a way to optimize the `System.currentTimeMillis()` call to either not have it or reduce how much time it takes? Is there another faster call I can use?

Comment: `System.nanoTime()` is better suited for your purpose (timing how long something takes). Also see [Time measuring overhead in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640409/time-measuring-overhead-in-java).

Comment: You can do a check how many operations are done in one second and check the time any N operations. You might lose half a second here or there but it will improve ;) For example if you aim at millions you can do the timing check every 50k attempts. It will be : while ( your condition ) {
for 1:50000 { do that operations } }

Comment: You're calling `System.currentTimeMillis()` 283130850 times in the loop? I really think there is a better way - implement `tick` and chose when you want to check is the given time less than current time.

Comment: *"I'm using to get the current time with respect to the end time is causing a lot of overhead"* - Define overhead; it is what is called a "busy loop", a loop which invokes as many times as the allotted CPU time allows. You may want to introduce a call to Thread.sleep() to make that loop a little less CPU hungry - and also reduce the amount of method calls done at the same time.

Comment: Generating a random integer is much more expensive than currentTimeMillis(). Try to profile your code.

Answer (score 3):

You should really be looking into [`System.nanoTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--) (and stick to that) - that is the best you can get in the JVM AFAIK. Besides the fact that it measures *elapsed time* without any notion of clock time, it is the fastest too - that is the reason [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) uses it (or any other sane micro-benchmark I hope).

Besides the fact that `System.currentTimeMillis` returns `ms` precision (and there are things that are done faster than `1ms`), the difference between two calls to this method [can return a negative value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978598/will-system-currenttimemillis-always-return-a-value-previous-calls).

There are two things to keep in mind though, first is that each call to `System.nanoTime` has a performance implication as well, on average it takes (on my, close to your CPU and JVM-9) `25 ns` per call.

The last point is that `System.nanoTime` has nano-second *precision*, but not nano-second *accuracy*. This means that when you call:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
long end = System.nanoTime();
```

both of the results will return a number that has nano-second precision, that is they will have multiple digits.

But that number can not be very accurate. Well, accurate according to what you might ask. Since `System.nanoTime` returns a value that is arbitrary, there isn't something to compare it with, unless other call to `System.nanoTime`, thus:

```
long result = end - start;
```

is/might not going to be a nano-second accurate result. The inaccuracy of this is around 1 micro-second, on my laptop is around 0.2-0.5 micro-seconds.

---

Use `System.nanoTime`, there isn't something faster or more fine-grained.

Comment: Okay, except I want to make the program run for a certain amount of time, that is, “n” seconds.

Comment: In addition, implementing `System.nanoTime()` rather than `System.getCurrentTimeMillis()` is actually much slower in this instance -- I can get 6,438,567 ops/second by using `System.getCurrentTimeMillis()`, whereas `System.nanoTime()` gets just 1,771 ops/second.

Comment: @DDPWNAGE I *just wonder* (irony face inserted here) if that is your code doing something fishy, vs `nanoTime` and `getCurrentTimeMillis`

Comment: I tried this myself also and `nanoTime()` is actually slower than `currentTimeMillis()`. The reason is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052316/why-is-system-nanotime-way-slower-in-performance-than-system-currenttimemill). In my system the difference is not that large though; `currentTimeMillis()` is maybe 3 times faster.

Comment: @MickMnemonic indeed! but 3 times faster is quite A LOT, I am around 5ns difference running via JMH https://justpaste.it/1h6d2

Comment: Apparently the difference depends quite a lot on the OS; I am using Windows where `currentTimeMillis()` is (apparently) fast.

Comment: I’m running Windows myself, @Mnemonic. Eugene , I posted the entire loop - I’m using time as a break condition.